# Python Find the words in the set have word pairs on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, join

I have set of words

```
{'DNA',
 'pada',
 'yang',...}
```

I am trying to find whether the words in the set have word pairs on the following bigram dataframe

```
                bigramf    freq
0           (DNA, yang)      15
1          (DNA, dalam)       6
2            (DNA, ini)       5
3       (DNA, memiliki)       4
4         (DNA, unting)       4
5           (pada, DNA)       4
6        (pada, urutan)       3
7     (yang, diperoleh)       3
8         (yang, lebih)       3
9      (pada, sejumlah)       2
10          (pada, RNA)       2
11          (pada, satu)      2
12       (yang, berbeda)      2     
13          (yang, sama)      2
14       (yang, tumpang)      2
```

If so, then the expected output will be like this:

```
yang [('lebih', 3), ('diperoleh', 3), ('berbeda', 2), ('tumpang', 2), ('sama', 2)]

DNA [('yang', 15), ('dalam', 6), ('ini', 5), ('memiliki', 4), ('unting', 4)]

pada [('DNA', 4), ('urutan', 3), ('sejumlah', 2), ('RNA', 2), ('satu', 2)]
```

How do I find?. Can anyone can help? Thanks. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First convert column with tuples to new 2 columns (dont use `apply(pd.Series)`, because [`slow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/35491399#35491399)), then filter matched values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and convert in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) values to list of tuples:

```
s = {'DNA',
 'pada',
 'yang'}

df[['s', 'v']] = pd.DataFrame(df['bigramf'].tolist(), index=df.index)

s = df[df['s'].isin(s)].groupby('s')['v','freq'].apply(lambda x: list(map(tuple, x.values)))
print (s)
s
DNA     [(yang, 15), (dalam, 6), (ini, 5), (memiliki, ...
pada    [(DNA, 4), (urutan, 3), (sejumlah, 2), (RNA, 2...
yang    [(diperoleh, 3), (lebih, 3), (berbeda, 2), (sa...
dtype: object
```

If need dictionary add [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = s.to_dict()
print (d)
{'DNA': [('yang', 15), ('dalam', 6), ('ini', 5), ('memiliki', 4), ('unting', 4)], 
 'pada': [('DNA', 4), ('urutan', 3), ('sejumlah', 2), ('RNA', 2), ('satu', 2)], 
 'yang': [('diperoleh', 3), ('lebih', 3), ('berbeda', 2), ('sama', 2), ('tumpang', 2)]}
```

Another solution with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for (s1, v1), f1 in df.to_numpy():
    if s1 in s:
        d[s1].append((v1, f1))

d = dict(d)
print (d)
{'DNA': [('yang', 15), ('dalam', 6), ('ini', 5), ('memiliki', 4), ('unting', 4)], 
 'pada': [('DNA', 4), ('urutan', 3), ('sejumlah', 2), ('RNA', 2), ('satu', 2)], 
 'yang': [('diperoleh', 3), ('lebih', 3), ('berbeda', 2), ('sama', 2), ('tumpang', 2)]}
```

Comment: can you explain me what do u mean with `isin(s)`?

Comment: @ohai - Sure, it test if first values of bigrams are in sets `s = {'DNA',
 'pada',
 'yang'}`

Comment: @ohai - In second solution is used `if s1 in s:` with same effect

Answer (score 0):

What I did is for matching words

I looped through the data frame and took each element and passed it to a def like this

```
def match_words(actual_word, word):
    return set(actual_word.split()).intersection(word.split())
```